Building with cmake : 100% Linking CXX executable ...fails
I am able to compile the code but when it is linking-time something does not work as expected.
I investigated a bit, and the problem is that the objects files used by the linker are 'empty'.
Likely, the build process is considering only the headers file and nothing else, but I have not idea how to fix it.
To replicate the problem just do as follow:
pi@raspberrypi:~/pico $ git clone  git@github.com:ozw1z5rd/PicoMite.git -b hcg20-WIFI PicoMiteHCG20-WIFI 
Cloning into 'PicoMiteHCG20-WIFI'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 3480, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (217/217), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (153/153), done.
remote: Total 3480 (delta 121), reused 130 (delta 64), pack-reused 3263 (from 1)
Receiving objects: 100% (3480/3480), 8.19 MiB | 976.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (2235/2235), done.
pi@raspberrypi:~/pico $ cd PicoMiteHCG20-WIFI/
pi@raspberrypi:~/pico/PicoMiteHCG20-WIFI $ git branch 
* hcg20-WIFI
pi@raspberrypi:~/pico/PicoMiteHCG20-WIFI $ mkdir build 
pi@raspberrypi:~/pico/PicoMiteHCG20-WIFI $ cd build/ 
pi@raspberrypi:~/pico/PicoMiteHCG20-WIFI/build $ cmake .. 
pi@raspberrypi:~/pico/PicoMiteHCG20-WIFI/build $ make -j4 
Scanning dependencies of target bs2_default
:

100%] Linking CXX executable PicoMiteWeb.elf
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/8.3.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/PicoMiteWeb.dir/PicoMite.c.obj: in function `routinechecks':
PicoMite.c:(.time_critical.routinechecks+0x4c): undefined reference to `tud_cdc_n_connected'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/8.3.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: PicoMite.c:(.time_critical.routinechecks+0x8e): undefined reference to `tud_cdc_n_read'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/8.3.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/PicoMiteWeb.dir/PicoMite.c.obj: in function `SerialConsolePutC':
PicoMite.c:(.text.SerialConsolePutC+0xd6): undefined reference to `tud_cdc_n_connected'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/8.3.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/PicoMiteWeb.dir/PicoMite.c.obj: in function `main':
PicoMite.c:(.text.startup.main+0x350): undefined reference to `tud_cdc_n_connected'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/8.3.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: PicoMite.c:(.text.startup.main+0x3bc): undefined reference to `stdio_usb'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/PicoMiteWeb.dir/build.make:3331: PicoMiteWeb.elf] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1913: CMakeFiles/PicoMiteWeb.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:103: all] Error 2

You can verify  that into the build folder some of the object files produced actually are "empty". Thus, the linker does not find the required symbols and fails.
For example, it it look at the cdc_device.c.obj used:
pi@raspberrypi:~/pico/PicoMiteHCG20-WIFI/build $ ls -l CMakeFiles/PicoMiteWeb.dir/home/pi/pico/pico-sdk/lib/tinyusb/src/class/cdc 
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 740 Aug 18 18:34 cdc_device.c.obj

It is just 704 bytes instead of 7184
The file has no symbols:
pi@raspberrypi:~/pico/PicoMiteHCG20-WIFI/build $ objdump -t  CMakeFiles/PicoMiteWeb.dir/home/pi/pico/pico-sdk/lib/tinyusb/src/class/cdc/cdc_device.c.obj 

CMakeFiles/PicoMiteWeb.dir/home/pi/pico/pico-sdk/lib/tinyusb/src/class/cdc/cdc_device.c.obj:     file format elf32-littlearm

SYMBOL TABLE:
00000000 l    df *ABS*  00000000 cdc_device.c
00000000 l    d  .text  00000000 .text
00000000 l    d  .data  00000000 .data
00000000 l    d  .bss   00000000 .bss
00000000 l    d  .comment   00000000 .comment
00000000 l    d  .ARM.attributes    00000000 .ARM.attributes

It should be:
cdc_device.c.obj:     file format elf32-littlearm

SYMBOL TABLE:
00000000 l    df *ABS*  00000000 cdc_device.c
00000000 l    d  .text  00000000 .text
00000000 l    d  .data  00000000 .data
00000000 l    d  .bss   00000000 .bss
00000000 l    d  .text._prep_out_transaction    00000000 .text._prep_out_transaction
00000000 l     F .text._prep_out_transaction    00000048 _prep_out_transaction
00000000 l    d  .text.tud_cdc_n_connected  00000000 .text.tud_cdc_n_connected
00000000 l     O .bss._cdcd_itf 000002c8 _cdcd_itf
00000000 l    d  .text.tud_cdc_n_get_line_state 00000000 .text.tud_cdc_n_get_line_state
00000000 l    d  .text.tud_cdc_n_get_line_coding    00000000 .text.tud_cdc_n_get_line_coding
00000000 l    d  .text.tud_cdc_n_set_wanted_char    00000000 .text.tud_cdc_n_set_wanted_char
00000000 l    d  .text.tud_cdc_n_available  00000000 .text.tud_cdc_n_available
00000000 l    d  .text.tud_cdc_n_read   00000000 .text.tud_cdc_n_read
00000000 l    d  .text.tud_cdc_n_peek   00000000 .text.tud_cdc_n_peek
00000000 l    d  .text.tud_cdc_n_read_flush 00000000 .text.tud_cdc_n_read_flush
00000000 l    d  .text.tud_cdc_n_write_flush    00000000 .text.tud_cdc_n_write_flush
00000000 l    d  .text.tud_cdc_n_write  00000000 .text.tud_cdc_n_write
00000000 l    d  .text.tud_cdc_n_write_available    00000000 .text.tud_cdc_n_write_available
00000000 l    d  .text.tud_cdc_n_write_clear    00000000 .text.tud_cdc_n_write_clear
00000000 l    d  .text.cdcd_init    00000000 .text.cdcd_init
00000000 l    d  .text.cdcd_reset   00000000 .text.cdcd_reset
00000000 l    d  .text.cdcd_open    00000000 .text.cdcd_open
00000000 l    d  .text.cdcd_control_xfer_cb 00000000 .text.cdcd_control_xfer_cb
00000000 l    d  .text.cdcd_xfer_cb 00000000 .text.cdcd_xfer_cb
00000000 l    d  .bss._cdcd_itf 00000000 .bss._cdcd_itf
00000000 l    d  .comment   00000000 .comment
00000000 l    d  .ARM.attributes    00000000 .ARM.attributes
00000000         *UND*  00000000 tu_fifo_remaining
00000000         *UND*  00000000 usbd_edpt_claim
00000000         *UND*  00000000 usbd_edpt_xfer
00000000         *UND*  00000000 usbd_edpt_release
00000000 g     F .text.tud_cdc_n_connected  00000030 tud_cdc_n_connected
00000000         *UND*  00000000 tud_mounted
00000000         *UND*  00000000 tud_suspended
00000000 g     F .text.tud_cdc_n_get_line_state 00000014 tud_cdc_n_get_line_state
00000000 g     F .text.tud_cdc_n_get_line_coding    00000020 tud_cdc_n_get_line_coding
00000000         *UND*  00000000 memcpy
00000000 g     F .text.tud_cdc_n_set_wanted_char    00000014 tud_cdc_n_set_wanted_char
00000000 g     F .text.tud_cdc_n_available  00000018 tud_cdc_n_available
00000000         *UND*  00000000 tu_fifo_count
00000000 g     F .text.tud_cdc_n_read   00000028 tud_cdc_n_read
00000000         *UND*  00000000 tu_fifo_read_n
00000000 g     F .text.tud_cdc_n_peek   00000018 tud_cdc_n_peek
00000000         *UND*  00000000 tu_fifo_peek
00000000 g     F .text.tud_cdc_n_read_flush 00000020 tud_cdc_n_read_flush
00000000         *UND*  00000000 tu_fifo_clear
00000000 g     F .text.tud_cdc_n_write_flush    00000078 tud_cdc_n_write_flush
00000000 g     F .text.tud_cdc_n_write  00000034 tud_cdc_n_write
00000000         *UND*  00000000 tu_fifo_write_n
00000000 g     F .text.tud_cdc_n_write_available    00000018 tud_cdc_n_write_available
00000000 g     F .text.tud_cdc_n_write_clear    00000018 tud_cdc_n_write_clear
00000000 g     F .text.cdcd_init    0000007c cdcd_init
00000000         *UND*  00000000 memset
00000000         *UND*  00000000 tu_fifo_config
00000000         *UND*  00000000 mutex_init
00000000 g     F .text.cdcd_reset   0000002c cdcd_reset
00000000         *UND*  00000000 tu_fifo_set_overwritable
00000000 g     F .text.cdcd_open    000000b4 cdcd_open
00000000         *UND*  00000000 usbd_edpt_open
00000000         *UND*  00000000 usbd_open_edpt_pair
00000000 g     F .text.cdcd_control_xfer_cb 000000dc cdcd_control_xfer_cb
00000000  w      *UND*  00000000 tud_cdc_line_coding_cb
00000000  w      *UND*  00000000 tud_cdc_line_state_cb
00000000         *UND*  00000000 tud_control_xfer
00000000  w      *UND*  00000000 tud_cdc_send_break_cb
00000000         *UND*  00000000 tud_control_status
00000000 g     F .text.cdcd_xfer_cb 00000104 cdcd_xfer_cb
00000000         *UND*  00000000 tu_fifo_empty
00000000  w      *UND*  00000000 tud_cdc_rx_wanted_cb
00000000  w      *UND*  00000000 tud_cdc_tx_complete_cb
00000000  w      *UND*  00000000 tud_cdc_rx_cb

Of course, I can get the final binary by replacing the content of the build folder with the correctly compiled version from another project. In this case, I have to start the linker manually. Fortunately, it is possible to get the command line  to be used from  the output of make -j4 --trace
How can I fix the CMakeFiles.txt file to avoid the empty files?

"the problem is that the objects files used by the linker are 'empty'" - those object files are created by the compiler. Probably, the problem is on the compiler side: either it is wrong, or your toolchain incorrectly configures it. You may start from inspecting a command line used for invoke the compiler for a particular object file. You may also run this command line manually, and check the created object file.

Good idea, let me investigate a bit.

I found the problem. Some defines were undefined. A good start point to resolve the problem.

Although this is a very simple question, I leave the answer to others who  may find this simple answer quite useful.
The root cause are the defines. While the cmake considers all the files that are supposed to be required, the C-preprocessor skips parts of the code that are required because of the #if inside of them.
Hence, you get empty object files from not empty C files.
Yep, quite ridiculous problem.

I'm glad you found a solution. Your answer would be much more useful, and I would be inclined to then vote for it if it identified what #define(s) were giving you problems. And, if they happened to be PICO_SDK_PATH, PICO_EXTRAS_PATH, etc. a link to the PIco_SDK page providing the instructions for setting them.  Good luck with your pico coding, the pico and the pico_sdk make it one of the most capable and usable microcontrollers out there, and for $4 ($5 with pin-headers soldered), it's hard to beat.

I'm working on it. I just found where the problem actually is.

Drop a comment after the update so I know to swing back by!

https://github.com/ozw1z5rd/PicoMite/tree/hcg20-WIFI

That code builds great! Simply did a clone, then mkdir build; cd build; cmake ../PicoMite no cmake issues, then just make and all built well, e.g. -rwxr-xr-x  1 david david   730892 Aug 22 17:58 PicoMite.bin The slower_boot2.bin also builds as well.

It was little tricky; finally the fire has been tamed. :)

Great job. Update this answer with a description of what you did to get the fire put out and I'll vote for it :)
